# justify a text by using PDFBox

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I heard that it's impossible to write a paragraph with PDFBox, so simply we can use moveTextPositionByAmount to create each line individually in order to draw our own paragraph.

But my problem is:

It's possible to justify a text by using PDFBox ?

Please i need your help :)

Best regards,

Liszt.

Comment: Calculate the "natural" length of your line. Count the number of spaces (excluding the last one). Divide the difference of natural vs. justified length by the number of spaces; then this amount needs to be added or subtracted to each space on drawing.

Comment: @Jongware only adding extra width to space characters would look unnatural. I would propose also adding some width to the gap between any two neighboring glyphs,  i.e. Not only words spacing but also character spacing use.